# how to pass string data with markerOptions in typescript

Tags: angular, leaflet, customization

Is there a way to add custom properties to `leaflet.marker.options`?

I need the markers to contain string related to the location, preferably in the marker options as that is already return by our service.

this is how the marker is created:

```
const marker = fromLeafLet.marker(
            fromLeafLet.latLng(station.latitude, station.longitude),
            {
                title: station.name,
                icon: fromLeafLet.divIcon({
                    className: stationClass

                })
            }
        );
```

I understand that

```
fromLeafLet.CircleMarker.extend({
    options:{
       customOption:'blah'
    }
});
```

could be use, however this is not an option available for `fromLeafLet.marker` or `const marker`, since I am using typescript, simply adding a new property `marker.newPropString` won't work either.

using leaflet in typescript w/ angular 4

Comment: What about  `customMarker = L.Marker.extend({
    options: {
        location: ''
    }
});` ? And then initialise via `const marker = new customMarker([lat, lon],{
    location: 'your-location',
})`

Comment: It didn't really let me do that, I ended up doing `marker.addEventListener('click', event => { callFunction({id: object.id})})`